# Can I figure out in iOS whether the app is resuming from standby or from multitasking

Tags: ios, background, multitasking, resume

I'm currently working on a change request for our iPad app that requires that I handle the resuming of the app in two different ways depending on whether the app returned from multitasking (the user was active in another app or on the homescreen and came back to the app) and standby (the iPad was switched to standby either through the standby button on top or by closing the Smart Cover)

In both cases the following methods are called in my `AppDelegate`:

- `applicationWillResignActive` followed by `applicationDidEnterBackground` when I hit the homebutton to get tot he home screen or close the Smart Cover
- `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` when I come back.

As the same methods are called I am a bit lost on how to detect where I come from on resume. All four methods have a single parameter passing in the `UIApplication`. I looked at its interface, but didn't find any useful clues.

Is there a way to differentiate between resuming from multitasking or standby?

Answer (score 1):

There is no public api method to define why application did become active